# How to separate one graph to different new graphs?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr

I have a database which includes laws per different years from 1985-2012. I would like to make different 17 plots (and thus, to make a function) for each year that will include its' values and the years before, and to keep the same design of x and y axis for each graph, as you can see in [the following figure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnqK4.png)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnqK4.png]

That's how I made the graph above, between 1985-2012:

```
> v <- ddply(leg.by.melt, .(year), summarise, count = sum(value))
> v
   year count

    1  1985     2
    2  1987     5
    3  1988     9
    4  1989    12
    5  1990    14
    6  1991    11
    7  1992    16
    8  1993    23
    9  1994    25
    10 1995    10
    11 1996    11
    12 1997    24
    13 1998    35
    14 1999    32
    15 2000    24
    16 2001    22
    17 2002    65
    18 2003    42
    19 2004    56
    20 2005    42
    21 2006    47
    22 2007    36
    23 2008    16
    24 2009    54
    25 2011    28

> ggplot(v, aes(x = year, y = count)) 
+ theme_bw() 
+ geom_contour(colour = "black", lty = 3, lend = 2, lwd = 1, stat = "identity") 
+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(v$year), max(v$year), by = 1),1)) 
+ scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(v$count), max(v$count), by = 3),1)) 
+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.2))
```

As I wrote before, I would like to have a different 17 plots - for 1985, for 1985+1986, for 1985+1986+1987 and so forth, and stil to have the same design of the x and y axis (x axis from 1985:2012 and y axis from 2 to 65).

How can I make a function to achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you plot is called `p`, I would do the following,

```
plyr::l_ply(v$year, function(.year) p %+% subset(v, year <= .year), .print=TRUE)
```

Comment: I would like to ask you another question: How can I keep the same design of the x and y axis (x axis from 1985:2012 and y axis from 2 to 65)? In the current function, each graph has different axis' values. Thank you in advance.